# Python Scrapy Extract Value of aria-label

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and I'm trying to scrape a page that has an aria-label on a class:

```
<body>
  <div class="item-price" aria-label="$1.99">
    .....
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to extract the label with the following parse on my spider:

```
def parse(self, response):
   price = circular_item.css("div.item-price > aria-label::text").extract()
   yield price
```

When I run the spider I get the following error:

```
2018-09-02 18:34:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'list' in <GET https://example.com/test.html>
```

How do I extract the value of aria-label here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your code:

```
def parse(self, response):
   item = {}
   item["price"] = response.xpath('//div[@class="item-price"]/@aria-label').extract_first()
   yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a css extractor instead of xpath:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = {response.css('div.item-price::attr(aria-label)').extract_first()}
    yield item
```